# Multiple processes wait for the same Future to complete (scala)

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I dont have a direct use for it now but this question just popped up in my head and couldn't find a good answer online:

I have a function 'callExactKeyFromDB' that returns: Either[A, Future[A]] (A= from local in memory cache, Future[A] = query the DB). Can I pass that Future to different threads/executions contexts and have all of them register on the 'onComplete' or is it better that each time this function is called I return a new future, keep a list of registered futures and complete them once I can.

Now the question is can I do it with 1 Future and should I do it?

(Imagine 4 processes requesting user information from the DB and are waiting for it to continue)

Comment: 1) You can compose `Futures`, e.g. `List[Future]` into `Future[List]` but whether you should it's a different story. 2) Post code to put everything into context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can register multiple callbacks with single `Future`. This requires less code, less memory, and is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of  `Either[A,Future[A]]` and transform it into a `Future[A]` to start with.

```
def getUserByKey(key:Int) : Future[User] =
  cache.users.contains(key) match {
    case true  => Future(cache.users(key))
    case false => Future(User(key = 101, name = "John Doe")) // db call
  }
```

It would make things a lot simpler, I guess...

If `cache` is shared between contexts, once is saved there's no need to make more calls to the database to get that particular user.

```
def saveUserCache(u:User) : Future[Unit] = Future{
  cache.users.contains(u.key) match {
    case true  => cache.users(u.key) = u
    case false => cache.users += (u.key -> u)
  }
}
```

Then one can mix these futures creating other futures

```
def renderUser(key:Int) : Future[String] =
  for {
    user   : User    <-  getUserByKey(key)
    update : Unit    <-  saveUserCache(user)
    output : String  <-  Future(s"${user.key}: ${user.name}")
  } yield output
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I see of why you would want to get rid of the Either but here is the trade off: What is fundamentally faster if I need to call the next() function, a pattern match(or even 2 ifs) on an Either or returning a completed future?